# How to resize base64 image before saving it to storage?

Tags: php, laravel, image

I am storing a `base64` encoded image to the `storage` like so:

```
Storage::disk('public')->put('example.jpg', base64_decode($src));
```

but how do I resize the image before storing it? Analogously to the `Image::make()->resize` method, I've tried:

```
$width = 200;
$height = 100;
Storage::disk('public')->put('example.jpg', base64_decode($src))->resize($width, $height);
```

which doesn't work:

```
local.ERROR: Call to a member function resize() on bool
```

Is there a convenient way or do I have to create a new `Image` facade to make `resize` possible?

Comment: `base64_decode($src))` gets you a string value, that does not have any `resize` method. You will need an actual Image instance, of you want to be able to use methods of that class.

Comment: The `resize` in my case is applied not to the `base64 string` but to the `put()` function of `Storage` facade.

Comment: I doubt that makes sense to begin with. I looks like that returns a boolean in any case (?, assuming the put itself did not fail here, you probably got a `true` returned) - so you can't call any methods on that. Plus, `put` is a generic method, and has nothing in particular to do with images - it is for writing _any_ sort of data to the disk, so why should it offer a `resize` method anyway? "Resizing" a text file or an mp3, for example, that would not even make sense ...